# Best practices to optimize memory in C#

Tags: c#, memory-leaks

What are the best practices to optimize memory in C#.

I am using following technique to optimize my memory.

1. Dispose an object after use or make it null.
2. Use try/finally or using block.
3. Use GC.Collect() if required.
4. Remove unnecessary object initialization.
5. Manage Image caching.
6. Mange BLOB data, Memory stream and file stream

Even if there is memory leakage.

My application is using following things:

1. Processing configuration files,
2. Using other XML files.
3. Using image functions zoom-in, zoom-out, display different type of images, changing color of images, saving data in xml.
4. Saving data in SQL server.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: Why do you think you have to do any of this, other than the `using` blocks? C# doesn't usually suffer from memory leaks.

Comment: There are *very* few cases, where you should manually call `GC.Collect`.

Comment: There is no one way to "optimize" memory, I think you need to describe your problem so it can be diagnosed first. What do you mean by "Even if there is memory leakage"? 

If you don't have a problem (yet) then you should wait with "optimizing" until you have a concrete issue. Meanwhile, just follow best practices such as using Dispose correctly.

Comment: I am not able to track that from where memory is leaking.

Comment: If data is being used as class level then how can I use using block for that.

Comment: If disposable data is used in a field of your class, then that class should also be IDisposable, and whoever uses it should use `using()`. For tracking down memory leaks use a profiler such as CLRProfiler or ANTS Profiler.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use **Redgate ANTS Memory profiler** (non-free).

Or **CLR profiler** (free): https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms979205

`GC.Collect()` is not recommended even if it is required in some cases. Please have a look at below code:

```
private void WriteStringOnImage()
{
    try
    {
        byte[] imgData = getData(@"E:\0000.tif");
        using (System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(imgData)))
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
            {
                Bitmap img1 = new Bitmap(new Bitmap(img));
                RectangleF rectf = new RectangleF(800, 550, 200, 200);
                Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img1);
                g.DrawString(i.ToString("0000"), new Font("Thaoma", 30), Brushes.Black, rectf);
                img1.Save(@"E:\Img\" + i.ToString("0000") + ".tif");
                g.Flush();
                g.Dispose();
                img1.Dispose();
                GC.Collect();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception){}
}
```

In the above example I used `GC.Collect()` because If I do not use `GC.Collect()` then it is taking memory around **1500mb**. But after use of `GC.Collect()` if is never exceeding than **75mb**

i.e. Memory utilization is **decreased by 20 times**.

But if `GC.Collect()` is being used excessively and there are not much unused objects lying in the memory then  `GC.Collect()` will slow down your performance and it is time consuming.

You can also use `Dispose()` if it implements `IDisposable`.

If you are working with `MemoryStream` or any other type of stream, then you should use the `using` blocks.

Sometimes you also need to **empty some object by making it `null`**.

As we know data if we process XML data then it takes very heavy memory so we need to free the memory after use but XML class doesn't implement Idisposable interface so you have to make it null (e.g. `xmldocument=null;`)

You should also keep in mind about **unnecessary object initialization**.

e.g. Instead of:

```
ClassA abc=new ClassA();
abc=xyz;
```

Use:

```
ClassA abc=xyz;
```

Try to use method level variable instead of class level if it is being used in only one method.

Make sure you are clearing collection objects.

Keep watch on the memory usage by any third party tool which is being used in your application. Sometimes third party tools takes very high memory.

**Use `static` only if it is must.**

**Use `StringBuilder` instead of `String`.** Because if string is concatenated then a new memory is allocated so the old memory data is not being used but it is kept in RAM.

If any large object is being processed in hierarchical classes keep watch on it.

**If any XML document is processed and has been kept in memory for future use and that will be use after any event then release that memory and load XML when the required event is fired.**

**Avoid cloning.**

If You are working with string manipulation you can check the data for infinite loop. Sometime special Unicode characters like ellipsis(...) can create problem and causes for infinite loop.

You can also use **dotTrace** a memory profiler by Jetbrain.

You can also look into **event log** for any exception which is causing the issue.

If any **bitmap object** is being created and some image processing is being done then have a look on unmanaged Resources. A **bitmap object take a huge memory for unmanaged resources** and that might not be released.

As you have mentioned that you are also using SQL server then also keep watch on **SQL server procedures and functions** and their calling strategies.

In SQL Server if you are saving any data as image data type and if it is larger than 1mb then please use **varbinary(MAX) with filestream** property but it will work with SQL server 2008 or upper versions of SQL server.

Comment: Do not call GC.Collect() explicitly several times. It will be time consuming.

Comment: I have used Redgate memory profiler but it is not helping me much.

How could I see that from which class memory is leaked or what unnecessary object is still in memory?

Redgate profiler is showing me that 55% (400mb) memory is being used for unmanaged code.
But I am unable to see what unmanaged code is taking memory.

Comment: Have you got the latest version of the RG profiler? v8 - released very recently - lets you poke around in that unmanaged block a bit.

Answer (score 5):

Many of these don't really optimize memory...

1. **Dispose an object after use or make it null.**  Always `Dispose()` an object if it is `IDisposable`.  This COULD save you memory problems, but not necessarily. (Also, use `Using` if possible)
2. **Use try/finally or using block.**  `try/finally` - This is similar to `Using` for objects that aren't `IDisposable` (I find them to be messy, so I prefer [this](http://www.artisansoftware.blogspot.com/2013/12/using-statements-with-proxies.html) solution.)
3. **Use GC.Collect() if required.** I wouldn't really be able to ever recommend `GC.Collect()`. Normally the `GC` will do a better job on knowing when to collect something than you will.
4. **Remove unnecessary object initialization.**  This one can definately help.  If your code is going around creating objects that aren't needed... then this could waste some space.  This can be sorta allievated/masked with [Lazy Initialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997286%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
5. **Manage Image caching.**  This is VERY vague... but yes... its important to manage how many images you have stored in memory.  It may not always be desirable to keep images in memory... It can open the door to paging for other processes in your code that are more critical.
6. **Manage BLOB data, Memory stream and file stream**  I think this is similar to #5.

Comment: What is the best way to free memory if a class is not implementing IDisposable interface?

Comment: Well it depends when you say "free memory".  The GC will take care of any arrays and what not you have.  However, if you have something like a `FileStream` open, then that needs to have its `Dispose()` method called.  If you make a class, that has members that implement `IDisposable`, then you should make your class implement `IDisposable`.

Answer (score 2):

`..or make it null` does not have the same effect than `Dispose()`!
Be careful. You only should dispose your object. Set to `null` is not required 
And set to `null` does not immediate free any resources.

> 3. Use GC.Collect() if required.

Normally this is not required, because the GC has his own lifecycle when to collect. Since .NET 4.5 you can compact the LOH, if you think there is a fragmentation:

```
GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode = GCLargeObjectHeapCompactionMode.CompactOnce;
GC.Collect();
```

Comment: But I am using framework 4.0 not 4.5.

Answer (score 2):

best practices to optimize memory in C#,

1. Create only the objects as and when needed
2. Decide the scope for each variable and object, if they are required inside methods declare them inside those methods, do not make them `private`
3. Use the `IDisposable` interfaces on your custom objects and release all the resources(if any), un-register from all the events etc
4. Call `dispose` when an object is no long required for your custom objects
5. Use least `static` variables or instances, if required then too think twice whether those objects are required in entire lifetime of program
6. Do not use `GC.Collect()` manually,(it is bad practice)