# Memory layout optimization in C#

Tags: c#, performance, memory, optimization, jit

Disclaimer : there might be some misconceptions in the phrasing below, please correct me if i misinterpreted the wy my code is handled in C# between the moment i write it to the point it looks like zeroes and ones

**The questions are the following (those are linked) :**

Is there any way in C# where my Data structures and/or my data manipulation implementation, will have a performance impact whether I use optimization techniques or not?

What does the compiler do when outputting IL, is it reliable? 
Meaning : if i make my data SOA will it be SOA in IL? Always?

What happens to my data structure when the JIT reads the IL? is it changed? is it optimized automatically to fit my processor?

cf: [that talk about C/C++](http://channel9.msdn.com/events/Build/2013/4-329)

I know that this talk is targeted at native code, and talks about the specifics of the processor layout vs your data layout in native code.

I also know the C# compiler and the JIT compiler will optimize stuff for me in regards of those issues.

Basically I wonder if those kind of optimization will have an impact on my perfs :

- SOA instead of AOS
- Vectors access patterns (to be accessed contiguously in memory)
- etc... you name it...

I work in game development and performance is critical, we manipulate large amounts of data and we need to do that minimum 24 times per second, I cannot have the GC do stuff for 300ms or memory to be accessed/allocated all over the place when I'm trying to detect collisions between 3000 different objects

For reference about stuff i read but did not really answer the question :

- [Excellent Eric Lippert article about structs and values types in C#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/04/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-two.aspx) (please read it if you think values types are always on the stack in C# you're in for a treat)
- [Excellent video about PerfView to track your GC behaviour and it's impact on your perfs](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-125-PerfView-Part-8)
- [That SO question about Best practices to optimize memory in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21046409/best-practices-to-optimize-memory-in-c-sharp) (and more importantly it's answer)

But those do not answer the performance cost relative to processor and data layout implementation.

---

To go further after what Hans answered :

When you say : "You can pursue SOA but that doesn't help. Yes, your program will slow down because of all that structure copying and does so in a deterministic way. But it doesn't stop the rain. You get the worst of both, a slow program and the exact same pauses."

It does not mean that my program benefits nothing from SOA it WILL be faster (potentially) because it will help processing my data. Just that it will have no impact on the GC in itself.

Other thing is that If i do not do SOA or other improvements in my data layout, the compiler won't improve that for me right? i cannot rely on the compiler to deal with that kind of things?

Comment: If you are talking about this level of stuff, C# (or any managed memory environment) is likely not for you. But then again...are you working in Real Time Computing, Financial Computation, Big Data etc?

Comment: Realtime but C# can be used properly to give that level of control i hope

Comment: The layout isn't fundamentally changed.

Comment: @GéryArduino By definition, Real time and Garbage Collector are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @Aron you can use some programming techniques in C#, like object pooling/preallocation in order to avoid allocations (that's called *zero alloc* / *gen zero* in the lingo). There are even [plugins helping you with this](https://github.com/controlflow/resharper-heapview). Granted, that's not idiomatic C# anymore, it's *hard* to get right, it needs extensive profiling, but it sure *is* possible.

Comment: @Aron No they are not. Hard real-time is rather exotic, but soft real-time and GCs is anything but uncommon. There's a whole specification for Java (RTSJ) and there are GCs that guarantee you a maximum pause time of a few hundred microseconds.

Comment: @Voo Soft RT is hardly the point where you deal with the GC, assuming your GC is performant and you don't do stupid things like string concat in a tight loop.

Comment: @Aron The point is that real-time and GC are definitely not mutually exclusive and if you use special GCs you can even do hard real-time. Iirc the software for some US fighter jets is written in Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Worrying about the GC is like worrying about whether it is going to rain today.  It is going to rain sooner or later, nothing you can do to stop it.  And it is *required*, you can't keep that lawn look pretty green if it doesn't.  What you never want to do is intentionally stop it from raining.  Because if you do it will come down in a deluge, spilling away that pretty lawn.  A steady drizzle is what you want.  And preferably at night when you're not looking.

The .NET GC strongly supports this.  Only the small gen #0 and #1 collections will pause your program.  The expensive gen#2 collection happens in the background while your code continues executing.  Worst-case pause hovers somewhere near a hundred microseconds.  Which is pretty indistinguishable from *other* reasons your program will pause on a modern OS.  Like your game loop getting suspended temporarily because another higher priority kernel thread needs to run.  Just a drizzle, unobservable to the human eye.

You can pursue SOA but that doesn't help.  Yes, your program will slow down because of all that structure copying and does so in a deterministic way.  But it doesn't stop the rain.  You get the worst of both, a slow program *and* the exact same pauses.

Don't worry about the rain, just make sure it comes down at the right time.  To take advantage of background GCs you want to structure your data so it is either very short lived, so it disappears easily with a gen #0/1 collection.  Or lives for very long so it finds a comfortable home in gen #2 and stays there for a while.  Which in general is a very common pattern in programs, especially so in games.  Pretty unlikely you need to do anything at all.

Comment: "You can pursue SOA but that doesn't help" - huh? I don't see any reason why the GC would have any effect on the memory access patterns of the program and the consequent effects due to caching, etc. Also at least for .NET 4.5 (even with SustainedLowLatency mode) it's just not true that there aren't any stop-the-world GCs - they're just rarer than before.

Comment: No real idea how your comment is relevant, please post your own answer.

Comment: I thought one reason for comments was to dispute facts posted in answers and ask for clarification or correction instead of just downvoting answers.

Comment: Thanks Hans for that great answer, i updated my question asking for some clarifications

Comment: It is inconclusive whether SOA is more efficient. It usually isn't because you have too many A but the only way to find out for sure is to measure. You do get help from the jitter (not the compiler), it tries hard to make S efficient when it can. The usual .NET guidance applies, structures are efficient when they have no more than 4 members so they fit in available processor registers. Beyond that the copying starts to bog down the code.  In practice the structure ends up on the heap anyway, as a field of a "Manager" class.  In which case you're not ahead at all.

Comment: Thanks that probably answer all my questions! for now... optimization in C# seems to be a bigger terrain than what i expected, when you talk about the .Net guidance do you refer about a specific document?

Comment: @Hans The reason SOA can be better than AOS is when you don't need all members of the struct for a computation. In that case you won't waste your cache with the unneeded members. There are other cases where AOS will be better - it depends very much on the use case, but how you lay out your data structures in memory is probably *the* most important performance optimization one can do these days. Independent if assembly or C#.

Comment: The reasoning needs to go beyond SOA and AOS, because large regularly structured data could have more than two tiers. Consider this: A large contiguous array of value objects (structs), with multiple fields, and some of its fields are arrays. The keyword is **cache locality**, and the rule-of-thumb is to put "data that is often used together (in time) close together (in space)". Streaming (speculative cache prefetch) is only relevant when one is truly streaming (reading sequentially); it doesn't help when one's use case is random seeking.

Comment: I think the verdict should be clear: the only scenario for which this question is relevant is if the software performance critically depends on some operations where very large amounts of primitive-type data are processed sequentially at very high throughput. When that happens, using primitive-type arrays may improve performance. Outside that scenario, the entire question and discussion is irrelevant.