# how to clear cache memory of a Blazor webapp by code

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

My Blazor server side app is using too much cache when the process run.
i want at the end of the process make a clear of all the webapp cache on the IIS server.
i need to code it at the end of the process by code but dont know how ....

[image: Here is the Worker Processes on IIS]

we can see my app on the last row...

and here from the TaskManager we can see it...

[image]

Comment: There's no "automatic" cache unless you enabled it. IIS won't cache data or HTML output unless explicitly configured. Even then, its size is limited. This looks like a memory leak in the application code.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for your suggestion, but how do you think we can fix it? and from where is the leak..? or an alternative solution like restart the webapp on the iis ...?

Comment: Use the [Diagnostic Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/beginners-guide-to-performance-profiling?view=vs-2019) window during debugging to see the memory usage in real time. If it keeps increasing over time, there's a leak. If you see a sawtooth image, with usage dropping after every GC, the code generates lots of temporary objects, eg strings. Strings are immutable so every string operation generates new strings. Parsing a CSV file by splitting lines and fields can result in a *lot* of garbage that needs to be collected

Comment: You can use the [Memory Usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/memory-usage?view=vs-2019) tab in the Diagnostics window to check how many instances of each type there are, how much memory they use, and whether new instances were generated since the last snapshot

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes i have lot of parsing csv file parsing... and the memory tab show me memory increasing like you said but only when i start my process with all the csv file parsing, it take above 1h of work and can go up to 12GB of memomy but how to realase this cache when my job is finished? you speak about a GB? Garbage Collector? how to empty this garbage ?

Comment: You'll have to change your code. You haven't posted it, so it's impossible to guess what's wrong. If you split the entire file, it's certainly wrong. If you insert all items into a `List<>` item by item, you'll waste memory too, as the `List` will have to reallocate its internal buffer a lot. Using a library like CsvHelper will reduce memory usage. Passing a `capacity` to the List constructor will allocate a large-enough buffer from the start, avoiding reallocations. There are other techniques too, like reusing buffers or using ArrayPool

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks, i work with xlsx sorry not csv, i get big datatable from db and create list. After i loop to put all data in a template xlsx... above 750k lignes..
i saw there is a `System.GC.Collect();` function i dont know if it will work i will try tonight or maybe you already know that will not work.... ?

Comment: Have you considered app pool recycle? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationHost/applicationPools/add/recycling/

Comment: @NicoleLu-MSFT thanks, yes i considered it but the pb with this solution is that its ok for the cache, it clear it well but my blazor server app is down ... and i have a scheduler with hangfire who is planed to work every week... so when the recycle is done, hangfire didnt restart until i ping the web app url on a browser to make it restart ...

Comment: Check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization , it helps your web app stay active, and will send a request to activate your application every time it restarts.

Comment: thanks @NicoleLu-MSFT but it seems not working with Balzor webApp... i had already saw that solution ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didnt find THE SOLUTION but here is what i understood and what i can share.

There is no ONE solution because its more about
-> how you code and all good practrise you use ...

yuo can read this topic [best pratcises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21046409/best-practices-to-optimize-memory-in-c-sharp) very interesting.

Actually, in my case, i had to clean little more my code and write some .Dispose() fonction everywhere i can without breaking my app to clean my code and it work.

Ex: when i use a datatable and finish to work with it, i just had to write a datatable.Dispose();